# How to receive WM_COPYDATA from command prompt?

Tags: cmd

I'm using a program's API that apparently sends `WM_COPYDATA` messages by `hwnd`.

I'm using the current line `tasklist /v /fo csv | findstr /i "Command Promt"` to get the `hwnd` of my command prompt.

But how can I display the `WM_COPYDATA` received? According to the docs I should be receiving them but I don't see anything.

Comment: To receive window messages you need a window. Using the console window for that is possibly not a good idea because it is not yours in the first place. You could create a (hidden) window from your console application acting as a receiver for such messages. [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36043832/21567)

Comment: @Christian.K Why not posting this as an answer? Sounds profound to me and deserves a more prominent place than a comment.

Comment: @Antares Because it is too short for a proper answer and the actual proceeding has already been explained (see the "Related" link). Best, this is a duplicate of a number of other questions on SO.